# Display only certain values from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, model-view-controller, view, lambda

I am trying to display only the values that apply to a certain item from a model.
I have list that contains the names of the attributes in the model that i want to display. this is the code that i have (and doesn't work)

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.attributes)
        {
            var attribute = item.Attributename;
            var value = Model.Equals(attribute);
            <dt>                    
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => value)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => value)
            </dd>
        }
```

what would work is this:

```
            <dt>                    
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </dd>
```

but I dont want name to be hardcoded in, thats why i have it in my list.
"Name" and some other values are saved in the attributes list.
What i would actually like to happen is something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.(ListItem.attributename))
```

So my question is: Is it possible to place a variable after the "model."?
I know this might be a litle bit confusing but i hope i have supplied enough information, if not please feel free to ask for more.

Comment: Not clear what your asking. `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)` will display the value of `Name` not _"display all fields"_

Comment: I'm sorry @StephenMuecke it indeed is a litle bit vague, but i dont want Name in `(model => model.Name)` hardcoded in because sometimes the values that i want to display will change.

Comment: is your model a class?  you'd need some kind of reflection to get the property values by name

Comment: @JamieD77 it is actually an entity that i get from a database, but that is almost the same right?

Comment: @JamieD77 At the moment order doesn't really matter

Comment: Why not use a ViewModel with only the fields you want?

Comment: @enki.dev I will look into ViewModel now

Answer (score 0):

If order isn't determined, and without writing a method to get the property values by name.  you could just write your view like this..

```
@{
    var attrList = ViewBag.attributes as List<Attribute>;
}
<dt>                    
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
</dt>
@if (attrList.Any(a => a.Attributename == "Name"))
{
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
}
etc..
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that is not really what i meant, im sorry that    my question is hard to understand. the thing is, that i dont want model.`name` hard coded in, `Name` is speccified in the attributelist. then foreach item in attributelist (e.g `name`, `Amount_of_hours`, `ServerID`) it has to display a value from the model (which is an item from a table from the database)